Unity Collision Detection with Raycasts off center
I was making a 3D game in Unity, and I was setting up a collision detection system with raycasts, and it seemed off center.
My code was:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private float movementSpeed = 7f;
    [SerializeField] private float rotationSpeed = 10f;
    [SerializeField] private float playerSize = .7f;

    [SerializeField] private GameInput gameInput;

    private bool isWalking;

    private void Update() {
        Vector2 inputVector = gameInput.GetMovementVectorNormalized();

        Vector3 moveDir = new Vector3 (inputVector.x, 0f, inputVector.y).normalized;

        bool canMove = !Physics.Raycast(transform.position, moveDir, playerSize);

        if (canMove) {
            transform.position += moveDir * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        isWalking = moveDir != Vector3.ze
        transform.forward = Vector3.Slerp(transform.forward, moveDir, Time.deltaTime *      rotationSpeed);
    }
}

I tried changing the player size, but it wouldn't let me go past a point which was about an inch away from the cube I was using to test. On the other side, I could go into the cube, but not all the way.

Your raycast checks in a distance of playerSize .. but then you move with moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime .. you should probably take that one into account as well ..

By default, the raycast starts at the player's pivot point (which is usually at the center of the GameObject). This can lead to a situation where the raycast is slightly off from what you'd expect, causing inconsistent collision detection.
Adjust Origin according to Player Size:
bool canMove = !Physics.Raycast(transform.position + Vector3.up * 0.5f, moveDir, playerSize);

Or you can use SphereCast.

By default, the raycast starts at the player's pivot point .. no. I think I see what you mean but the raycast starts at whatever point you provide as the start point ;)
